# NSSharingService - Remove facebook and twitter and add Print

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I've just implemented a share-button, that has a share menu:

```
 [_shareButton sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];
```

And has this action connected:

```
-(IBAction)share:(id)sender {   
    NSArray *shareArray = @[@"testShare"];
    NSSharingServicePicker *sharingServicePicker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:shareArray];
    sharingServicePicker.delegate = self;

    [sharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds]
                                      ofView:sender
                               preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
}
```

Now to my question, I don't want Facebook and Twitter to be an option in the menu. I only want E-Mail and Messages to be available. Also I would like to add "Print", but don't know if I can do that.

Is that possible?

Thanks

(Don't have enough rep points to add 'NSSharingService' as a tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using `proposedSharingServices`.

```
- (NSArray *)sharingServicePicker:(NSSharingServicePicker *)sharingServicePicker sharingServicesForItems:(NSArray *)items proposedSharingServices:(NSArray *)proposedServices{

// Find and the services you want
NSMutableArray *newProposedServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
for (NSSharingService *sharingService in proposedServices) {
    if ([[sharingService title] isEqualToString:@"Email"] || [[sharingService title] isEqualToString:@"Message"]) {
        [newProposedServices addObject:sharingService];
    }
}
NSArray *services = newProposedServices;

NSSharingService *customService = [[NSSharingService alloc] initWithTitle:@"Print" image:[NSImage imageNamed:@"PrintImage"] alternateImage:nil handler:^{
    // Do whatever
}];

services = [services arrayByAddingObject:customService];

return services;
```

}

Comment: It's important to note that the title property is localized, so "Email" and "Message" will likely be different if the app is not running in English.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a proposed service to a new named instance works. Here's a trivial Swift code from my project:

```
let excludedNames = [
    NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook,
    NSSharingServiceNamePostOnTwitter,
]

var excludedServices = [NSSharingService]()

for name in excludedNames {
    if let service = NSSharingService(named: name) {
        excludedServices += [service]
    }
}

return proposedServices.filter {
    !excludedServices.contains($0)
}
```

No need to use a private `name` property.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then trying to say what you don't want simply return a list of what you do want.

```
- (NSArray<NSSharingService *> *)sharingServicePicker:(NSSharingServicePicker *)sharingServicePicker sharingServicesForItems:(NSArray *)items proposedSharingServices:(NSArray<NSSharingService *> *)proposedServices
{
    NSArray *result = @[[NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail], [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeMessage]];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach via `proposedSharingServices`:

```
- (NSArray*)sharingServicePicker:(NSSharingServicePicker *)sharingServicePicker sharingServicesForItems:(NSArray *)items proposedSharingServices:(NSArray *)proposedServices {

    NSArray *excludedServices = @[NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook,
                                  NSSharingServiceNamePostOnTwitter];

    NSArray *sharingServices = [proposedServices filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (name IN %@)", excludedServices]];

    return sharingServices;
}
```

Comment: This is a much nicer solution than looking at the title property, since that changes based on the language, but unfortunately the name property seems to be private. So while this works great now, it could break in an OS X update, and might not pass App Store review.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way - no private API access required.

```
NSArray *excludedServices = @[NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook,
                              NSSharingServiceNamePostOnTwitter];

NSMutableArray *includedServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSSharingService *service in proposedServices) {
    if ([excludedServices indexOfObject:service] == NSNotFound) {
        [includedServices addObject:service];
    }
}

return includedServices;
```

Comment: This does nothing. You're looking for `NSSharingService` match in array of `NSString`'s (i.e. just names).